# How to implement url redirect rule for multiple parameters in querystring in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I have a url with 2 parameters in query string, How to rewrite to a friendly url and redirect it permanantly.

My page name is results.aspx

The url is

http://localhost:22507/results.aspx?c=abc&qry=some-text

My rewriting rule

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite rule 1">
      <match url="^results/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="results.aspx?c={R:1}&amp;qry={R:2}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

The url doesn't change. What is the mistake?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are thinking in reverse. It does not change `/results.aspx?c=abc&qry=some-text` to `/results/abc/some-text` but the other way around so that the url `/results/abc/some-text` typed in the browser is translated to `/results.aspx?c=abc&qry=some-text` to form a working url.

Comment: Hi.. Thank u for ur reply. Both the url are working. That is /results.aspx?c=abc&qry=some-text and /results/abc/some-text. It is not working in the reverse way i.e. the second url doesn't get converted to the first. I want the 1st url to redirect to 2nd

Comment: That will send your site into a redirect loop. you will always need a url in this format `/results.aspx?c=abc&qry=some-text`. So when it is converted it becomes `/results/abc/some-text` that needs converting back to the original to work etc etc.

Comment: oh.. so how can I solve this problem of getting url /results/abc/some-text on entering url /results.aspx?c=abc&qry=some-text

Comment: Your rewriter takes care of that, it works as it should.